# How to get value from 'ir.property' model. Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

I want to get value of standard_price of the main company in compute field of standard_price.
I tried with this code but showing always 'False' value.

Any help please ??

Here is my code:

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    @api.depends_context('company')
    @api.depends('product_variant_ids', 'product_variant_ids.standard_price')
    def _compute_standard_price(self):
        st_price = self.env['ir.property']._get(self.with_context(company=self.env.ref('base.main_company')).standard_price,"product.product")
        _logger.info('------st_price:%s', st_price)

        # Depends on force_company context because standard_price is company_dependent
        # on the product_product
        unique_variants = self.filtered(lambda template: len(template.product_variant_ids) == 1)
        for template in unique_variants:
            template.standard_price = template.product_variant_ids.standard_price
        for template in (self - unique_variants):
            template.standard_price = 0.0
```

Result : ------st_price:False

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `force_company` as context flag and "reload" the records:

```py
main_company = self.env.ref('base.main_company')
main_company_templates_prices = {
    t.id:t.standard_price for t in 
    self.with_context(force_company=main_company.id)
}
for template in self:
    main_company_standard_price = main_company_templates_prices.get(
        template.id, template.standard_price)
    # do something
```

Comment: when printing 'main_company_standard_price', I got always 0.0 value , even I set a value of cost for main_company, @CZoellner

Comment: can you try to use `sudo()`? I mean in the dictionary comprehension: `self.sudo().with_context(force_company=main_company.id)`

Comment: @ CZoellner, same issue :/

Comment: The main objective was : I have company A with Inventory valuation configuration (avco/automated) and  company B  with Inventory valuation configuration  (standard/manual)

If I have standard_price value in company A,when I switch from company A to B,  I want to get same value in company B , actually I get always 0.0 value. @CZoellner